# Wget doesn't create index file of directory

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download site with command:

```
wget -r -l 0 -p -k -m -e robots=off --restrict-file-names=nocontrol,unix http://example.com
```

When it finds the link, for example, `http://example.com/direction`, it creates a file on the disk `./example.com/direction`

Then, for example, it finds some other files (links) in 'direction', suppose `http://example.com/direction/11`

And `wget` rewrite old file `./example.com/direction` with some HTML, and transform it into the directory. And write new file `./example.com/direction/11` there.

If it finds a new file inside `/direction/11`, then it'll rewrite `11` as well and convert it into the directory.

So, it seems, I've lost all directory index files.

Is there a solution for the problem in wget itself?

Answer (score 2):

This may not work in every case, but I was able to solve this problem using a somewhat unexpected tag.

From the wget 1.17.1 manual:

> `‘-E’`
>
> `‘--adjust-extension’`
>
> If a file of type `‘application/xhtml+xml’` or `‘text/html’` is downloaded and the URL does not end with the regexp `‘\.[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]?’`, this option will cause the suffix `‘.html’` to be appended to the local filename.

Thus, in your case, when wget finds the link `http://example.com/direction`, it will check whether the page is html-formatted. If so, it will save it to the local disk as `/example.com/direction.html`. Then when it sees `http://example.com/direction/11`, it will save it to the disk as `/example.com/direction/11`, thus not overwriting the first file. Assuming that the true directory structure is `/example.com/direction/index.html`, it won't exactly match the remote directory structure, but at least it won't incorrectly overwrite files.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a solution to this issue using only Wget is nigh impossible. Let me first try and explain the issue to you.

First Wget attempts to download, `http://site.com/direction`. When Wget sends a request for this path, the server responds with the data available in `http://site/com/example/index.html`. However, at this point, Wget is not aware that the data being sent to it corresponds to the path: example/index.html. Now, when Wget finds another file, `http://site.com/example/11`, the same things happens again. However, it must first create the directory example/ and it unconditionally deletes the old file to do this. IMO, Wget should detect if it is replacing a file with a directory and save the file as an index file. But, as of now it doesn't.

Comment: I think you are right that it is impossible with `wget`. However, I found a solution in a combination with `find` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/703786/89346): one should download each directory manually.